# Call a control method from another function vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am wondering if it is possible to use the method associated with a control from another function.  For example

```
Sub myCheckBox(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles myCheckBox.CheckedChanged
'''Code I want to run from other function
End Sub

Function MyOtherFunction(x as double, y as double) as double
'''Call myCheckBox method
End function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is generally wise to limit code in events to handling user related things.  You can place common code in subs and call them from events, other methods (Subs) and other functions:

```
  Sub myCheckBox(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles myCheckBox.CheckedChanged
     ' user / click related code
     ' ...
     CommonReusableCodeSub(sender As object)
  End Sub

  Function MyOtherFunction(x as double, y as double) as double
     ' do some special stuff, maybe even just to prep
     ' for the call to a common sub
     CommonReusableCodeSub(Nothing)
  End function

  Sub CommonReusableCodeSub(chk as CheckBox) ' can also be a function
      ' do stuff common to both above situations

      ' note how to detect what is going on:
      If chk Is Nothing then
         ' was called from code, not event
         ' do whatever
         Exit Sub      ' probably
      End If

      Select Case chk.Name     ' or maybe chk.Tag
          chk.thisOption
            ' do whatever
          chk.thatOption
            ' do whatever
          ' etc...
       End Select

  End Sub
```

This prevents app logic (business/web etc etc etc ) from getting hopelessly intermingled and even dependent upon the UI layer and current layout.  Note: some controls implement a way to call event code: buttons and radios for instance have a `btn.PerformClick`, no such luck with checkboxes.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply and I appreciate where you are coming from.  In this case however, I have a lot of checkboxes that need to be "refreshed" ie. their code run when a radio toggle changes.  The way things are setup I loop through the checkboxes determine which ones are checked on and then need to run the method for each checkbox.

Comment: still doable with a bit of abstraction...see edit  (is the checkbox really a radio?)

Comment: "Is checkbox really a radio" -- no what I have is a graphing application where there are 10 checkboxes that show different curves and a radiobutton that manipulates the curves, so when the user changes the radio toggle I need to refresh the curves.

Comment: that tells me the code to draw the curves has no business in the checkchanged event: you do not want to draw ONLY when the user clicks, but as a result of other things.  assuming the checks represent some sort of parameter for the curves, they should pass that param to a procedure that does the drawing.  The parameter represented by each checkbox could be stored in the Tag property and used in either my answer or Don's.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming WinForms:

```
Dim cbs = Me.Controls.OfType(Of Checkbox)().Where(Function(cb) cb.Checked).ToList()
For Each cb In cbs
  'run code for each checkbox that is checked
Next
```

Comment: Right, that is what I have so far, now I need to run the method for each cb.

Comment: @KyleTrainor you are thinking about this wrong: the code you want to run is not a `method` at all, but event code: code intended to execute when the USER interacts with the control.  Your code (such as to perform a calculation) ought not depend solely on that click and ought not reside in the click event.

Comment: You need to give us more details, this does not make much sense at this point. What function? What does it do? How does 'which checkboxes are checked' do some calculation? Please update your question and not a comment.